# withRouter: history.push() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, browser-history

I would like to do an additional action when navigating - so I wanted to navigate programmatically. This doesn't seem to work as intended.

In my code I am using the withRouter HoC and history.push. The error I'm given is `history.push is not a function.` and sure enough, even though I have a history prop, there is no push function on there (only pushState, replaceState, go, forward, etc.).

I would really like to use history.push so that my route can update based on those changes not have to reload. How do I do this?

Edit: Code looks like this, basically:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.goTo = this.goTo.bind(this);
  }

  goTo() {
    const {
      link,
      history,
    } = this.props;

    // other action
    history.push(link);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.goTo}>Text</button>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Component);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used?

Comment: It would be easy to help if you share some code

Comment: I added some code now.